# Getting empty object on importing react component from library even after adding output.library in webpack config

Tags: typescript, webpack, babeljs, babel-loader, ts-loader

I'm writing a sample typescript react component library with folder structure as shown below, exporting just 1 button component. On running npm run build, just one js bundle is generated. The bundle has the react library code (did not use externals property yet in webpack config) but not the exported button component with the button tag (on searching keyword button in bundle file, was getting no results). Have added the code of bundle/build file also.

Not sure where I'm going wrong.

This issue does not happen with webpack bundles while exporting simple javascript function i.e. the exported javascript functions are found in generated bundle but not exported react component.

---

Update :

After adding output.library.name = "template-react-component-library"
and output.library.type = "umd" in my webpack config , I was able to see the button tag (of exported component) in webpack bundle file but on importing the same button component from the template-react-component-library, I'm getting an empty object.
Moreover, with exposing normal javascript functions from a library with same webpack configuration, I'm getting the javascript function and not empty object on importing it from library and that also without adding any output.library configs.

So now the question is how to solve the empty object on importing component from the library and why output.library behaves differently in exposing javascript functions and react components.

---

Repository link : https://github.com/dhiren-eng/template-react-component-library

**Folder structure :**

[image: Folder structure]

**webpack.config.js :**

```
const path = require("path")
module.exports = {
entry: "./src/index.ts",
output: {
    filename: "main.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    clean: true
},
module: {
    rules: [
        { test: /\.(jsx|js|tsx|ts)$/, exclude: /node_modules/, use: {loader: "babel-loader", options: {presets: ["@babel/preset-env","@babel/preset-react"]}} },
        { test: /\.(tsx|ts)$/, exclude: /node_modules/, use: ["ts-loader"] }
    ]
},
resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.jsx']
}
}
```

**tsconfig.json :**

```
{
compilerOptions: {
"jsx": "react",
"module": "ESNext",
"declaration": true,
"declarationDir": "types",
"sourceMap": true,
"outDir": "build",
"moduleResolution": "node",
"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
"skipLibCheck": true,
"strict": true,
"forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
"esModuleInterop": true
}}
```

Installed below packages. **package.json :**

```
{
  "name": "template-react-component-library",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
     "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
     "build": "webpack --config webpack.config.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
  "@babel/cli": "^7.21.5",
  "@babel/core": "^7.21.8",
  "@babel/preset-env": "^7.21.5",
  "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
  "@types/react": "^18.0.27",
  "babel-loader": "^9.1.2",
  "react": "^18.2.0",
  "ts-loader": "^9.4.2",
  "typescript": "^4.9.5",
  "webpack": "^5.76.2",
  "webpack-cli": "^5.0.1"
}
```

**src/components/Button/Button.tsx :**

```
import React from "react";

export interface ButtonProps { 
  label: string;
}

const Button = (props: ButtonProps) => {
  return <button>{props.label}</button>;
};

export default Button;
```

**src/components/Button/index.ts :**

```
export {default} from './Button'
```

**src/components/index.ts :**

```
export {default as Button} from './Button'
```

**src/index.ts :**

```
export {Button} from './components'
```

**Build file generated, main.js :**

```
    /*! For license information please see main.js.LICENSE.txt */
(()=>{"use strict";var t={408:(t,e)=>{Symbol.for("react.element"),Symbol.for("react.portal"),Symbol.for("react.fragment"),Symbol.for("react.strict_mode"),Symbol.for("react.profiler"),Symbol.for("react.provider"),Symbol.for("react.context"),Symbol.for("react.forward_ref"),Symbol.for("react.suspense"),Symbol.for("react.memo"),Symbol.for("react.lazy"),Symbol.iterator;var o={isMounted:function(){return!1},enqueueForceUpdate:function(){},enqueueReplaceState:function(){},enqueueSetState:function(){}},r=Object.assign,a={};function n(t,e,r){this.props=t,this.context=e,this.refs=a,this.updater=r||o}function c(){}function p(t,e,r){this.props=t,this.context=e,this.refs=a,this.updater=r||o}n.prototype.isReactComponent={},n.prototype.setState=function(t,e){if("object"!=typeof t&&"function"!=typeof t&&null!=t)throw Error("setState(...): takes an object of state variables to update or a function which returns an object of state variables.");this.updater.enqueueSetState(this,t,e,"setState")},n.prototype.forceUpdate=function(t){this.updater.enqueueForceUpdate(this,t,"forceUpdate")},c.prototype=n.prototype;var s=p.prototype=new c;s.constructor=p,r(s,n.prototype),s.isPureReactComponent=!0;Array.isArray,Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty},294:(t,e,o)=>{o(408)}},e={};!function o(r){var a=e[r];if(void 0!==a)return a.exports;var n=e[r]={exports:{}};return t[r](n,n.exports,o),n.exports}(294)})();
```

After running the webpack build, 2 folders are generated :

1. Types folder as mentioned in outDir property of tsconfig.json
2. Build folder generated by webpack

[image]

Comment: Why would you expect that to be part of the output?

Comment: If I'm bundling a file which exports a react component, so I would naturally expect react component in the bundle and since the react component renders button element, so I'll be expecting the button element also in the bundle

Comment: But the button element is part of the runtime environment. It's provided by the browser. There's no way for it to do what you're asking and it wouldn't make sense for it to do so either.

Comment: I mean to say that I'm expecting a button tag in the bundle. We will be needing the button tag as a parameter of the function of React.createElement(), in the bundle. Otherwise how will the runtime environment know what element to render ?

Comment: The `<button>` tag is compiled into a call to `reactDom.render(arguments)` where in one of the arguments indicates the element to be rendered.

Comment: To make things a little easier, can you share a link to your repo?

Comment: Here is the link to the repository : https://github.com/dhiren-eng/template-react-component-library

Answer (score 1):

OK where should I start? First let me say that I am heavily in favour of distributing libraries in ESM (Ecma Script Module or simply module) format, since it's the most promising, modern module format out there.

That doesn't mean you can't distribute your lib in other formats (eg. UMD) as well, but I will focus on ESM in my answer because it's the preferred way to consume component libraries in React apps.

#### Configuring Webpack

Now that we know we want Webpack to produce ESM output, let me tell you [Webpack's support for ESM is still experimental](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2933) so there might be issues along the way.

Let's change `webpack.config.js` to produce ESM:

```
  output: {
    ...,
    library: {
      type: "module",
    },
  },
  externals: {
    react: "react",
  },
  experiments: {
    outputModule: true,
  },
  ...
```

With this config, the output will contain something like `import * as React from 'react'`, which is what we want.

Now there is a problem, upon TS transpilation Webpack for some reason doesn't respect `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true` from TS config, which should make `import React from 'react'` work even though `'react'` doesn't provide any default export. But for some reason, the output still tries to retrieve `default` from `react`, which is not present. This leads to issues

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'createElement')
```

which means `react` wasn't resolved correctly.

I didn't find any ideal solution here, but what worked for me is this:

1. Add `externalsType: "import",` to `webpack.config.js`. This will import `react` dynamically, but is not desirable since it adds some 2kB of runtime to your output.
2. Use `import * as React from 'react'` in your source files.

Both of those work and make it possible to use your component with `import { Button } from 'your-lib';`. But they both also kinda suck.

#### Alternative

Which begs the question, if there isn't more appropriate bundler for libraries. I'd suggest Rollup, either directly or through Vite. Unlike Webpack, it has excellent support for ESM format out of the box.

Add `rollup.config.js`

```
import typescript from "@rollup/plugin-typescript";
import babel from "@rollup/plugin-babel";
import external from "rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external";
import terser from "@rollup/plugin-terser";

export default {
  input: "src/Button.tsx",
  output: {
    file: "build/main.js",
    format: "es",
    sourcemap: true,
  },
  plugins: [
    typescript(),
    babel({
      presets: ["@babel/preset-react"],
    }),
    external(),
    terser(),
  ],
  external: ["react"],
};
```

This config is a precise mirror of your Webpack config, and is imo easier to configure and read. Of course you have to install the needed dependencies

```bash
yarn add -D rollup rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external @rollup/plugin-babel @rollup/plugin-terser @rollup/plugin-typescript tslib
```

Another side effect is that Rollup's output, at least in your case, is much smaller, and basically amounts to:

```
import t from "react";
const e = (e) => t.createElement("button", null, e.label);
export { e as Button };
```

whereas Webpack's is much bigger.

PS: If you encounter problems because the Rollup config uses `import` and `export`, just add `"type": "module",` to your `package.json`, which will force your project files to use ESM instead of CommonJS (and its `module.exports` and `require()`).

Comment: Thanks. But 'react' package does provide default export which can be understood from the basic import statement in every react component i.e. import React from 'react'

Comment: No it doesn't. You can verify this by setting `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": false` in your tsconfig.json. It will throw an error which mentions the missing default export.

Comment: Thanks, I changed the webpack config to the one mentioned by you i.e. output.library.type="module",  externals.react="react" and experiments.outputModule=true without adding externalsType: "import" , but I never got the error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'createElement')" while running webpack build or importing from library . I'm still getting an empty object on importing from the library and it's the same even after adding externalsType: "import" in webpack config

Comment: I tried again with the changes for webpack config from my answer and it works still fine. How are you importing your library in your project? Also, can you share how your lib's main.js looks like?